# Way to pass changed parameter value. File or ...?

Tags: tcl

I'm total noob in tcl, but I have received quite complicated system (hardware and software) which uses tcl and I have to do one thing. This hardware has interfaces which I can read in tcl script. E.g. I can send command to read some voltage level and that hardware should respond with polled value (AFAIK it comes as tcl list with engineering value, raw value, etc.).

What I need to do is to create real-time (new value every one second) graph with that pooled value and I have to use graphing power of some data analysis software (DAS). Assuming that this software can use many data IO access ways, what is the best way to pass data values from tcl? E.g. I could write it to the file and then read file in DAS, but in this case I suppose will be the problem with access to opened file or even with synch.

I think it could be easier task if I could run tcl script from that DAS, but now it looks that it is impossible, it looks that scripts have to be started from that system specific software.

Any help, tips etc.. are greatly appreciated.

Best regards
bLAZ

Comment: While I like Vishwadeep idea with coding the GUI in Tcl/Tk, I need some more information: Where does Tcl run? On your machine or on the remote hardware? Could you please provide an example of the data you get (and what is the important value of it)?

Comment: Tcl runs on my machine. It runs from Terma TSC product (http://ccs.terma.com/index.html). I just started my holiday and I away from my lab, so unfortunately I can't provide any example. But in documents they say that it is Tcl list and they prepared functions to have access to that list items, e.g. getrawvalue, getengvalue, gettimestamp...

Comment: Ok, I'd use sockets. Write a small script that writes the current value to the socket.

Comment: Hmm, I read that socket is a TCP and I think this channel is good idea. It opens kind of server in system and then is it possible to have client access from the other application (e.g. my DAS) which can handle socket client protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a socket based approach:

```
# Use port 12345
socket -server accept_client 12345
proc accept_client {sock from port} {
    fconfigure $sock -blocking 0 -buffering line
    fileevent $sock readable [list readsock $sock]
    lappend ::clients $sock
}
proc readsock {sock} {
    catch {read $sock}
    if {[eof $sock]} {
       global clients
       set pos [lsearch -exact -- $clients $sock]
       if {$pos != -1} {
           set clients [lreplace $clients $pos $pos]
       }
       close $sock
    }
}

proc broadcastValues {} {
     global clients
     after 1000 broadcastValues
     if {![llength $clients]} {
         # No client connected
         return
     }
     # You have to modify the next line
     set data [lindex [GetTheDataHere] 1]
     foreach client $clients {
         # The data is seperated by a newline (\r\n)
         puts $client $data
     }
}

after idle broadcastValues
vwait forever; # Enter the event loop.
```

You can do additonal checks like passing `-myaddr 127.0.0.1` to socket if you only want it to listen on your local machine, or check if this IP may connect in accept_client (just `close $sock` if it should not).

You have to find out the index of the data you need yourself, I used `1`, that is the 2nd element of the list. And you have to replace `GetDataHere` with the command that returns the values.

The protocol is simple: A value per line, every second a new value.

Comment: perfect. we have reached till socket.. before writing my answer, i had never thought of this much complex way. thanks for increasing my level.

Comment: Great example! Please just make this clear for me, I can connect to the socket from any other application via port 12345, not necessary from Tcl script? And no problem when Tcl server writes to socket when another client reads?

Comment: It will send the values to every connected client. So you can connect several clients (even on other machines) that get all the values. And no, Tcl is not nessencary.

Comment: Excellent! Now I can really rest on my holiday with idea how to deal with it when I will be back :) I'm sure that I will have problems, but I will ask you sirs in 2 weeks ;) I really appreciate your both help.

Answer (score 3):

@Vishwadeep: you are thinking about this the wrong way. Instead of waiting for 1 period and then doing something, Tk supports *scheduling* a task to run after some delay. This uses exactly the same `after` command but you give it the procedure or script be be run when the delay expires. The difference between the two models becomes significant when you consider chaining a number of such readers together. So instead you should be using something like:

```
proc schedule_xx_update {interval} {
    variable id_xx
    set values [get_value_from_source]
    display_value $values
    set xx_id [after $interval schedule_xx_update]
}

proc stop_xx_updates {} {
    variable id_xx
    after cancel $id_xx
}

connect_to_device
schedule_xx_update 1000
vwait ::forever
```

The `vwait` at the end starts running the Tcl event loop. Before we enter that, we schedule a read and display function which will be run after the specified delay and will re-schedule itself to run again once it completes. Adding additional readers is fairly obvious.

For the original question: if you are using an API call or command to read the device output then the above should be usable. Possibly your device responds using a channel (file or serial channel) in which case you should investigate using `fileevent` instead which will raise an event to call a procedure when data becomes available on the channel.

Answer (score 2):

As much i understood, suppose "command" is a command which is resulting you the voltage value:
Hence Plot can be generated using tk canvas and values can be fetched using exec

Code:

```
    set width 500
    set height 500
    canvas .c -width $width -height $height -background white
    pack .c

    set oldx 0
    set oldy 0
    while {1} {
        after 1000; # After 1 sec
        set newy 0
        catch {set newy [exec command]}; # setting the newy value, means voltage value from "cmd" which is a shell command
        .c create line $oldx $oldy [expr $oldx+1] $newy; # will draw a line from previous plot point to latest plot point
        incr oldx; # increasing x values means time be 1 sec
        set oldy $newy
        puts "Updating for $oldx sec"
        update
    }
```

Comment: if returned value from the command is complicated, then you need to parse the information accordingly.

Comment: This approach is wrong. You block the GUI the entire time, and the GUI is unresponsive. I suggest an event based approach with `after 1000 updatePlot`

Comment: It looks good and Tk seems to be powerful, but may be not enough. Also another data will have to be calculated in that DAS and presented in GUI. There are specific toolkit and procedures, so I will be not able to use Tk graphs. This is why I have pass values there. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Blocking GUI will be the next obstacle. Now I would like to control just one parameter, but finally there will be more of them and I will have to present graphs for each one.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn in my thought approach is fine for 1 sec, but adding to your point only, bLAZ you can keep on append your values to any list variable, and when every user click on plot. You can update the plot with the latest values. It will not look unresponsive. Command: bind .c <1> {UpdatePlotFunction} .... Blocking GUI is not a big obstacle, there are lot of ways you can remove binding from canvas while freezing and rebuild them after unfreezing

Comment: Even updating the GUI only every 99ms is not good enough. (Yes, I already worked with something like that, althogh that called `Tcl_DoOneEvent`) Try it yourself: `while 1 {update; after 99}`